# How do I negate the following statements?

Tags: logic

I need help with these homework questions. Thanks in advance!

> i) $(a\land b) \lor (a\land b)$
>
> ii) $(a\Rightarrow b) \Rightarrow  (\neg c\Rightarrow (b\Rightarrow a))$

Here's what I have so far for each problem:

i) $\neg ((a\land b) \lor (a\land b))$

$ =(\neg a\lor\neg b) \land  (\neg a\lor\neg b)$

$=(\neg a\lor\neg b)$

I'm not sure if this is right but I was thinking of using De Morgan's rules for part i.

ii) I know when negating an implication, it goes as follows:

$(a\Rightarrow b) = (a\land \neg b)$

I'm not sure if I should start on the rightmost or leftmost side but any help would be appreciated for this!

Comment: You can just put $\lnot ( \dots )$ around all of them.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! Please see the edit we make to your question; you shouldn't write literal symbols for rendering, instead you must use LaTeX commands.

Answer (score 1):

General note: You use $=$ for saying "Equivalent propositions", but that's not 100% correct, since $=$ is a relation, so you want to use $\equiv$ or $\iff$.

For i) you did it well!

For ii), note the outermost parentheses, they will guide you where you must apply the equivalence $\neg(p\Rightarrow q)\equiv p\land\neg q$: $$\Bigl(a\Rightarrow b\Bigr) \Rightarrow  \Bigl(\neg c\Rightarrow (b\Rightarrow a)\Bigr),$$ so negating it:
\begin{align*}
\neg[(a\Rightarrow b)\Rightarrow(\neg c\Rightarrow (b\Rightarrow a))]&\equiv(a\Rightarrow b)\land\neg[\neg c\Rightarrow (b\Rightarrow a))]\\
&\equiv(\neg a\lor b)\land\neg(c\lor(\neg b\lor a))\\
&\equiv(\neg a\lor b)\land\neg c\land b\land\neg a.
\end{align*}

Hope you can finish.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your first statement $(a∧b)∨(a∧b)$ is the same as $P \vee P$ if we let $P = (a \wedge b)$. We know that

$$
P \vee P \iff P
$$

The negation of $P$ is then $\neg P = \neg (a∧b) = (\neg a \vee \neg b)$ by DeMorgan.

---

For the second statement, $(a⇒b)⇒( c⇒(b⇒a))$, we write the contrapositve,
$$
\neg (\neg a \vee b) \vee (\neg c \vee (\neg b \vee a))
$$
Now let's negate,

$$
\neg(\neg (\neg a \vee b) \vee (\neg c \vee (\neg b \vee a))) = 
(\neg a \vee b) \wedge \neg(\neg c \vee (\neg b \vee a)) =
(\neg a \vee b) \wedge (c \wedge \neg (\neg b \vee a))
$$

Can you finish distributing the negation using DeMorgan's?